# How can I compile this file

Tags: java, compilation

Sorry for wasting your time, but I am a complete noob in Java and can't seem to find a documentation that I can understand.

My only wish is to compile this application:

https://github.com/bela333/GrapplRelay

Thanks you if you are able to help, you're great!
And again sorry for wasting your time, but I am a complete noob in Java and can't seem to find a documentation that I can understand.

Comment: Have you looked up how to compile Java? 1000s of tutorials must exist for this.

Comment: It has a pom.xml file. 1) Install the JDK, 2) Install Maven, 3) `mvn install`

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

You create a folder for your project

```
mkdir repo
```

You enter the folder you have just created

```
cd repo
```

You clone the repository your project is in

```
git clone https://github.com/user/project
```

All these commands should be inputted into a terminal to make your GitHub repository available in your computer hard drive. After following the above mentioned you just proceed like you would do if you have started your project in your PC

If you don't want to do this you can download your repo in a ZIP file and extract it and proceed like you would do if you have started your project in a PC.

Comment: Most of the projects have a `README` on Github. It's displayed on the project repository by default. Also, projects generally mention step by step method on how to build it.